# Javascript with Ruby on Rails using Haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have _form.html.haml:

```
-@insurance = InsuranceProvider.pluck(:name)
=content_tag :div, class: "insu_information", data:{insurance:@insurance} do
```

In application.js file:

```
var x=$('.insu_information').data('insurance');
```

so if I put alert(x) then value is coming:

```
ravi,kant,ashish
```

No single quotes neither double quotes nor even bracket is coming.

I want output to be ["ravi","kant","ashish"] in one variable so that I can use this variable onward.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Chances are there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Try looking into http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript, and https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: Maybe dump the array to JSON in Ruby?

Comment: @steve:~ Thanks for advice but with gon game also coming same as before ravi,kant,ashish..But I want output like ["ravi","kant","ashish"].. but mine output still coming without single quotes or double quotes and without bracket ..

Comment: I got the Solution. Thanks..:):)